# Hw to automatically extract build instructions from a Continuous Integration service like Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

Suppose I have a repository powered with a CI service, such as https://github.com/TechPrimers/jenkins-example

Is there a way to automatically get the test commands and their build instructions?  Such instructions are used in the following use case:

- Mutate the source of the tests (e.g. unit tests in GoogleTest) with a third-party tool
- Compile the tests again
- Run the tests, which hopefully should generate more code
  coverage than original tests do. (The assertions in the original tests may no longer hold, but there should be a coverage gain with the the mutated tests at least)

In the case above, the Jenkinsfile shows the test is done with `maven test`, but how does it translate to the test source files and corresponding build and test instructions?

Comment: From where do you want the build instructions? Regarding the test, can you elaborate what do you want automatically? Do you want test commands or perform tests automatically?

Comment: I would like t find the test commands from the various sources, build scripts in the repository. Not sure if there is a standard place to get them in an CI-powered repo... Regarding the test I hope to get the test commands automatically in order to mutate test sources, compile, and run them in later iterations of the tests.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with test commands? Do you mean e.g. `mvn test` like in your example? Or do you mean to get a list of the exact test classes?

Comment: I am still confused. Can you give an example? It would be helpful in understanding your requirements.